# IBM Mobile First 7.1 - How to add Maps SDK for Android and iOS in IBM MFP 7.1

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

The project I'm working on uses IBM MobileFirst 7.1 with AngularJS, Ionic, Cordova. And now I've to add a map to a "view". The app is available for Android and iPhone. I could'nt find how to get Maps SDK for Android and iOS and how can I integrate it with IBM Mobile First?

I've already read the maps sdk documentation but i still don't know how to use in IBM MobileFirst.

Comment: You have to use javascript APIs

Comment: @CristianTraìna the js api have a limit of 2,500 requests per day and the sdk for android and ios are unlimited.